# Getting Typescript 2 paths mapping (aliases) working

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I am trying to reference custom modules shortcuts (ie use `ts` paths mapping feature) for my typescript app, with the following config.

**Project structure**

```
dist/

src/
  lyrics/
     ... ts files
  app/
     ... ts files
```

Full project structure is here: [github.com/adadgio/npm-lyrics-ts](https://github.com/adadgio/npm-lyrics-ts), dist folder is not commited of course)

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["src/lyrics/*"], // to much here !! but none work
            "zutils/*": ["./src/lyrics/*", "src/lyrics/utils/*", "dist/lyrics/utils/*"]
        },
        "rootDir": "."
    },
    "exclude": [
        "dist",
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

When i run my npm start/compile or watch script, i get no Typescript errors. The following works (Atom is my IDE)

```
// string-utils.ts does exist, no IDE error, typescript DOES compile
`import { StringUtils } from 'zutils/string-utils';`
```

But i then get the NodeJS following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'zutils/string-utils'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/adadgio/WebServer/projects/adadgio/npm-lyrics-ts/src/index.ts:7:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/adadgio/WebServer/projects/adadgio/npm-lyrics-ts/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:413:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/adadgio/WebServer/projects/adadgio/npm-lyrics-ts/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:416:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
```

It looks like the module is trying to be resolved from the `node_modules` folder. I've read docs about Typescript paths mapping but i cannot get it to work.

Comment: Paths are not re-written when the source is compiled. They are only used when the source is exported to a bundle (like SystemJS). This is the expected TypeScript behavior as I understand it, unfortunately.

Comment: Mindblowing, check the thread for details: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039. And here is a possible solution: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866#issuecomment-246929461

Answer (score 4):

I was doing lot of research on this. 
I am using atom, typescript and nodejs.

The thing is, when you compile typescript, it does search for paths (the path to a .ts file to include). However, the final compiled .js file does not get path substituted.

**The solution:**

- Compile ts files, use paths in tsconfig
- Use script to substitute path token in final .js files
- Run node application

So essentially, part of tsconfig will look like this

```
  "baseUrl": "./app",
    "paths" : {
      "@GameInstance" : ["model/game/GameInstance"],
      "@Map" : ["model/game/map/Map"],
      "@MapCreator" : ["model/game/map/creator/MapCreator"],
      "@GameLoop" : ["model/game/GameLoop"],
      "@Point" : ["model/other/math/geometry/Point"],
      "@Rectangle" : ["model/other/math/geometry/Rectangle"],
      "@Functions" : ["model/other/Functions"]

    }
```

And consider Rectangle.ts file

```
import { Point } from '@Point';
import { Vector } from '@Vector';
/**
 * Represents a rectangle.
 * You can query it for collisions or whether rectangles are touching
 */
export class Rectangle {
//more code
```

Where Rectangle.ts is in

```
./src/app/model/other/math/geometry/Rectangle/Rectangle.ts
```

We run

```
tsc
```

which will compile all .ts files we set up. There, the paths will be substituted in runtime, if you get error, run

```
tsc --traceResolution > tmp && gedit tmp
```

and search for the fiel wehere is undefined path include. You will be able to see substitution log

Then we are left with Rectangle.js (builded)

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var _Point_1 = require("@Point");
//more code
```

As you see, the @Point will not exist and we can not run node application like this.

For that, however, I created a script, that recursivelly searches js files and replaces the tokens by going up to root and then to target path.

There is requirePaths.data file where you define token and the path.

```
'@GameLoop' : "./app/model/game/GameLoop"
'@GameInstance' : "./app/model/game/GameInstance"
"@Map" : "./app/model/game/map/Map"
"@MapCreator" : "./app/model/game/map/creator/MapCreator"
"@Point" : "./app/model/other/math/geometry/Point"
"@Rectangle" : "./app/model/other/math/geometry/Point"
```

Now, this is NOT universal, it is just my hot script. Please, take a note, that structure is

```
src
|-app
|  |-model
-build
   |-src
      |-app
          |-model
|-test
```

Technically, the app/model... structure in src, is just copied to the src/build
The tsc takes source from /src/app and compiles it. Compiled result is in /src/build

Then, there is the substitutePathsInJS.sh script. 
This scand for build path, and whenever it finds token @Rectangle, it replaces it (more explanation below...) Code:

```
    #!/bin/bash

function testreqLevel()
{
  local srcPath="$1"
  local replacingIn="$2"
  local expectedLevel=$3
  getPathLevel "$replacingIn"
  local res=$?
  if [ ! $res -eq $expectedLevel ]; then
    echo "[-] test $srcPath , $replacingIn FAILED. ($res != $expectedLevel)"
  fi
}
function assertreqPath()
{
  local input="$1"
  local expected="$2"
  if [ ! "$input" = "$expected" ]; then
    echo "[-] test $expected FAILED"
    echo "computed: $input"
    echo "expected: $expected"
  fi
}
function testGetPathLevel()
{
  testreqLevel "./build/src" "./build/src/app/model/game/GameObject.js" 4
  testreqLevel "./build/src" "./build/src/file.js" 1
  testreqLevel "./build/src" "./build/src/app/model/game/GameObject.js" 4
}
function testGetPathToRoot()
{
  local path=$(getPathToRoot "./build/src" "./build/src/app/model/game/GameObject.js")
  assertreqPath "$path" "../../../../../"

  path=$(getPathToRoot "./" "./server.js")
  assertreqPath "$path" "./"

  path=$(getPathToRoot "./" "./app/model/game/GameInstance.js")
  assertreqPath "$path" "../../../"
}
function err()
{
  echo "[-] $1"
}
function getPathLevel()
{
  #get rid of starting ./
  local input=$(echo "$1" | sed "s/^\.\///")

  local contains=$(echo "$input" | grep '/')
  if [ -z "$contains" ]; then
    return 0
  fi
  #echo "$input"
  local slashInput=$(echo "$input" | awk -F/ '{print NF-1}')
  return $(($slashInput - 1))
}
#given ROOT, and PATH, returns a path P such as being in directory PATH, from there using P we get to root
#example:
#ROOT=./src
#PATH=./src/model/game/objects/a.js
#returns ../../
function getPathToRoot()
{
  local root="$1"
  local input="$2"
  getPathLevel "$input"
  local level=$?

  if [ $level -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "./"
    return 0
  fi
  for ((i=1; i <= level + 1; i++)); do
    echo -n '../'
  done
  #echo "$root" | sed 's/^\.\///'
}
function parseData()
{
echo "**************"
echo "**************"
  local data="$1"

  let lineNum=1
  while read -r line; do
    parseLine "$line" $lineNum
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
      return 1
    fi
    let lineNum++
  done <<< "$data"
  echo 'Parsing ok'

  echo "**************"
  echo "**************"
  return 0
}
function parseLine()
{
  if [[ "$1" =~ ^\#.*$ ]] || [[ "$1" =~ ^\ *$ ]]; then
    #comment line
    return 0
  fi

  local line=$(echo "$1" | sed "s/\"/'/g")
  let lineNum=$2

  local QUOTE=\'
  local WORD_IN_QUOTES=$QUOTE[^:$QUOTE]*$QUOTE

  if [[ "$line" =~ ^\ *$WORD_IN_QUOTES\ *:\ *$WORD_IN_QUOTES\ *$ ]]; then
    # valid key : value pair
    local key=$(echo "$line" | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sed 's/^ *//g' \
    | sed 's/ *$//g' | sed 's/\//\\\//g' | sed "s/'//g" | sed "s/\./\\\./g")
    local val=$(echo "$line" | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sed 's/^ *//g' \
    | sed 's/ *$//g' | sed "s/'//g")
    echo "[+] Found substitution from '$key' : '$val'"

    if [ -z "$REPLACEMENT_KEY_VAL" ]; then
      REPLACEMENT_KEY_VAL="$key|$val"
    else
      REPLACEMENT_KEY_VAL="$REPLACEMENT_KEY_VAL;$key|$val"
    fi
  else
    err "Parse error on line $lineNum"

    echo "Expecting lines 'token' : 'value'"
    return 1
  fi
  return 0
}
function replaceInFiles()
{
  cd "$WHERE_SUBSTITUTE"
  echo "substitution root $WHERE_SUBSTITUTE"

  local fileList=`find . -type f -name "*.js" | grep -v "$EXCLUDE"`

  echo "$fileList"| while read fname; do
    export IFS=";"
    echo "Replacing in file '$WHERE_SUBSTITUTE$fname'"
    for line in $REPLACEMENT_KEY_VAL; do
      local key=`echo "$line" | awk -F\| '{print $1}'`
      local val=`echo "$line" | awk -F\| '{print $2}'`

      local finalPath=$(getPathToRoot "./" "$fname")"$val"

      if [ $VERBOSE -eq 1 ]; then
        echo -e "\tsubstitute '$key' => '$val'"
        #echo -e "\t$finalPath"
        echo -e "\treplacing $key -> $finalPath"
      fi

      #escape final path for sed
      #slashes, dots
      finalPath=$(echo "$finalPath" | sed 's/\//\\\//g'| sed 's/\./\\\./g')

      if [ $VERBOSE -eq 1 ]; then
        echo -e '\t\tsed -i.bak '"s/require(\(.\)$key/require(\1$finalPath/g"\ "$fname"
      fi
      sed -i.bak "s/require(\(.\)$key\(.\))/require(\1$finalPath\2)/g" "$fname"
    done
  done
 return 0
}
function quit()
{
  echo "*************************************"
  echo "*****SUBSTITUTING PATHS EXITING******"
  echo "*************************************"
  echo
  exit $1
}
#######################################
CURRENTDIR=`dirname "$(realpath $0)"`
WHERE_SUBSTITUTE='./build/src'
REPLACEMENT_KEY_VAL="";
VERBOSE=0

FILE="$CURRENTDIR/requirePaths.data"
EXCLUDE='./app/view'

if [ "$1" = "-t" ]; then
  testGetPathLevel
  testGetPathToRoot
  echo "[+] tests done"
  exit 0
fi

if [ "$1" = "-v" ]; then
  VERBOSE=1
fi
echo "*************************************"
echo "********SUBSTITUTING PATHS***********"
echo "*************************************"
if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]; then
  err "File $FILE does not exist"
  quit 1
fi

DATA=`cat "$FILE"`
parseData "$DATA"
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  quit 1
fi
replaceInFiles
quit $?
```

This seems confusing, but consider excample.
We have Rectangle.js file.

The script loads bunch of input tokens from requirePaths.data file, in this case, lets focus on line

```
"@Point" : "./app/model/other/math/geometry/Point"
```

Script runs from ./src, and is given root directory ./src/build/src

Script does cd ./src/build/src

Executes find. There, it will receive

```
./model/other/math/geometry/Rectangle/Rectangle.ts
```

The absolute path of that is

```
./src/build/src/app/model/other/math/geometry/Rectangle/Rectangle.ts
```

But we do not care about absolute path now.

Calculates path such as he gets from the directory up
Whis will result is something like

```
./../../../../
```

Where he will like that get from directory

```
/src/build/app/model/other/math/geometry/Rectangle
```

to directory

```
/src/build/app
```

Then, behind that string, we add the path provided from the data file

```
./../../../.././app/model/other/math/geometry/Point
```

So the final substitution for file Rectangle.js (in BUILD folder somewhere) is

**before**

```
require("@Point")
```

**after**

```
require("./../../../.././app/model/other/math/geometry/Point")
```

Which is terrible, but we do not care about what is in js anyway. Main thing is that it works.

**Drawbacks**

1. You can NOT combine it with code monitor. Monitoring tsc and then, when change in code is done, do automatic tsc compile, then automatically run the shell path substitution and then tun nodeJS upon final js files is possible, BUT for some reason, then the sh script substitutes paths, the monitoring software considers is as change in code (no idea why, it has build excluded from monitor) and compiles again. Therefore, you gen an infinite loop
2. You must compile it manually, step by step, or JUST use monitor on tsc compilation. When you write some code, go and run substitution and test the nodeJS functionality.
3. When adding new Class Food, you must define a token for it (@Food) and path to file in 2 places (tsconfig) and the input for shell script
4. You make entire compilation process longer. To be honest, tsc takes most of time anyway, and the bash script is not so time consuming surprisingly....
5. When implementing tests with mocha, you must again do step by step compilation and when finished, run mocha above final js files. But for that you can write scripts....

Some people usually substitute only like @app or some directories. The problem with that is, whenever you move source file around, you have to do lot of changes...

**The good sides**

1. When moving file around, you change one string (in two places....)
2. No more relative paths that make big project impossible to maintain
3. It is interesting, but it really works, and I did not encounter major problems (if used properly)

Comment: Thank you. I tired looking for a solution, so you give me a confidence that I should write my own script, rather than spending time surfing internet. However I would use typescript for this purpose.

Comment: Glad to help. I would just like to add, that it might be better to use C++ (for performance), as my game server now compiles an hour like this when rebuilt.
I have improved the substitution script also in a way, that md5 hash of each source file is computed, substituting only in changed files. If you would need any help, (or I can send you entire script), contact me. Just warning: Writing your own script like that is extremely difficult, and time-consuming and frustrating...

Comment: I already wrote it:) It's much simpler than yours, as I was using node, for example to calculate relative path just use `path.relative(from, to)`.

Comment: Would you mind, please, sharing here an excerpt from the script? It would help me a lot, if the solution is simplier, and algorithmically faster (which I guess it is)

Comment: Here I created a git for you https://github.com/vtulin/ts-paths-compile, comments are in code, it's very simple, ask there if you need further assistance. Tested in Windows, but I think it should work on any platform.

Comment: I checked your code. It works nicely, but all the substitution happens at runtime. Therefore, this is not a suitable solution for projects, where you care about speed, as every single time you run the server, it executes substitution. Moreover, the substitution takes an insanely long time (seconds for only one entry!), script in bash is faster and runs only in compile time. Definitely not a solution for projects on Heroku, where system sleeps your application after 15 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: I posted just a piece of code, it abstract, I don't use it this way of course. I my personal case I subscribe to file change event, on this event I run recompile and then run substitutions. The substitutions code also not a genios creature:) it should check changes and skip a lot of files, but in my case it takes couple seconds, so I don't care about it. Is your project public, can I check why my code fails for you, bash shouldn't be much faster, actually their difference should be minimal in time, the only benefit in typescript method is to write all code in one language.