# How to resolve module not found on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, relative-path, module-alias

I am using module-alias within my nodejs application.
Locally everything works fine, the file path and modules are being found.

However, when deploying on Heroku none of my aliases are being recognized and this error occurs

`Error: Cannot find module 'app/models/socket.js'
app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin/www:17:21)
app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1`

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nameless",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "commit": "commit-wizard"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apn": "^2.2.0",
    "apn-test": "^1.3.1",
    "app-module-path": "^2.2.0",
    "async": "^0.9.0",
    "await-timeout": "^0.3.0",
    "aws-subdomain": "^0.1.2",
    "base64-img": "^1.0.3",
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.7",
    "bluebird": "^2.10.2",
    "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
    "change-case": "^2.1.6",
    "circle-to-polygon": "^1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "cron": "^1.3.0",
    "debug": "^4.1.0",
    "diet": "^0.16.0",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "~4.9.0",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "express-fileupload": "^0.3.0",
    "express-fileuploader-s3": "0.0.1",
    "express-sslify": "^1.2.0",
    "express-subdomain": "^1.0.2",
    "fb": "^1.1.1",
    "fcm-node": "^1.2.1",
    "fcm-push": "^1.1.3",
    "geocoder": "^0.2.3",
    "geojson-area": "^0.2.1",
    "geojson-polygon-center": "0.0.0",
    "geojson-rewind": "^0.2.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.0.12",
    "google-locations": "^0.1.2",
    "googleplaces": "^0.6.0",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.1.15",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^1.0.5",
    "gulp-replace-task": "^0.2.1",
    "gulp-run": "^1.6.6",
    "gulp-sloc": "^1.0.4",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.12.1",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.7.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "http-request": "^0.7.0",
    "instagram-api": "^1.0.3",
    "instagram-node": "git+https://github.com/andrewoodleyjr/instagram-node.git",
    "instagram-node-api": "^1.6.0",
    "instagram-node-lib": "^0.1.1",
    "jade": "~1.6.0",
    "json2csv": "^2.12.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.2.0",
    "knox": "^0.9.2",
    "linkedin-scraper2": "https://github.com/andrewoodleyjr/node-linkedin-scraper2/tarball/master",
    "mobile-detect": "^1.4.1",
    "module-alias": "^2.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.4",
    "mongoose-query-random": "^1.0.1",
    "mongoose-random": "^0.1.1",
    "mongoose-simple-random": "^0.4.1",
    "morgan": "~1.3.0",
    "multer": "^0.1.6",
    "ng-intl-tel-input": "^2.0.0",
    "node-cron": "^1.2.1",
    "node-foursquare": "^0.3.2",
    "node-foursquare-venues": "^1.1.0",
    "node-instagram": "^2.0.2",
    "node-linkedin": "git+https://github.com/andrewoodleyjr/node-linkedin.git",
    "nodemailer": "^1.3.0",
    "nodemailer-ses-transport": "^1.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.12",
    "opbeat": "^4.17.0",
    "polygon-centroid": "^1.0.0",
    "prerender-node": "^2.7.4",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "quickthumb": "0.0.11",
    "raw-body": "^2.3.2",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "sendy-api": "git://github.com/igord/sendy-api.git",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.5",
    "socket.io": "1.7.2",
    "stripe": "^6.3.0",
    "swagger": "0.0.1",
    "swagger-node-express": "^2.1.3",
    "swagger-tools": "^0.9.0",
    "tempie": "0.0.2",
    "timezone-compute": "^0.2.2",
    "timezoner": "^0.1.9",
    "twilio": "^3.11.3",
    "validator": "^3.27.0",
    "vhost": "^3.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.26.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "prettyjson": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@root": "./",
    "@db": "db/",
    "@models": "models/",
    "@util": "util/",
    "db": "db/db.js",
    "config.js": "config.js"
  }
}
```

**bin/www**

```
require('module-alias/register');

const SocketModel = require('@models/socket.js');
const app = require('@root/app.js');
```

Comment: you found a solution for this? I'm currently unable to deploy my app to hero and it's also using module-alias

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer unfortunately no

Comment: i've added a tentative workaround. See if it works in your case

Answer (score 1):

Note, this is just for last resort if no solution works yet.

Since the OP says that it builds and works in the local.

Just let typescript ignore those particular imports. Add `//@ts-ignore` for every imports with aliases. I know this is an ugly solution but nothing works so far.
Note that `module-alias` is still required for this workaround.

Since you said that it works locally then i believe just letting typescript ignore those files during build isn't that much of a big deal since all we care about is the files are compiled to javascript. Of course, you need to test the compiled js files just to be sure.

The problem is related with typescript not resolving path mappings to their corresponding paths during build.

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51044559/9732932). Check also the comments on that answer if you want to manually convert those path mappings on the compiled files.

Another relevant [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866).

Comment: PS: But I didn't use `module-alias`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the slashes at the end of the paths under "_moduleAliases" like so:

```
"_moduleAliases": {
 "@root": ".",
 "@db": "db",
 "@models": "models",
 "@util": "util",
 "db": "db/db.js",
 "config.js": "config.js"
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue...same error

Comment: Are you pushing the models folder to heroku as well? As far as I know heroku does not install anything other than the dependencies

Comment: yes, everything except dependencies is being pushed to heroku

Comment: @andrewoodleyjr What is your folder structure?